# How do I open a new workbench window (with its own WorkbenchWindowAdvisor) from an existing workbench window?

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp

I have a RCP applicaton from which I need to show a GEF Editor in a modal "dialog". But since the editor framework seems to be tightly coupled to the use of a workbench window etc I need to find a why to open a new workbench window (with its own WorkbenchWindowAdvisor etc) so that I can open my GEF editor within this workbench window. Once I get this workbenchWindow opened I will set the style of the WorkbenchWindow's shell to be application modal.

Answer (score 2):

I have done this in a customer project using the following components:

- A static class with a method `openNewWindow(String type, ...)`. This is the method you call to open a new window. The type argument specifies the wanted type of window.
- The class looks up the specified type via a new extension point to get an `ILocalWorkbenchWindowAdvisor` and the initial perspective ID.
- It then saves the information in global variables and calls `IWorkbench.openWorkbenchWindow(perspectiveID, ...)`
- In `ApplicationWorkbenchAdvisor.createWorkbenchWindowAdvisor(...)` a new advisor is create based on the saved `ILocalWorkbenchWindowAdvisor` - the returned advisor basically delegates all the `postWindowCreate(...)`, etc to the same methods in `ILocalWorkbenchWindowAdvisor`...
- If no `ILocalWorkbenchWindowAdvisor` is saved - which is the case for the very first window to be opened - the type "mainWindow" is looked up and used...

It works pretty well and let all parts of the project add new windows as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use the command "org.eclipse.ui.window.newWindow" to open a new window. In your WorkbenchWindowAdvisor.preWindowOpen(), set the shell style on the IWorkbenchWindowConfigurer to be application modal. You can also hide the coolbar, menu and status bars, so it looks more like a dialog than a window.

Comment: Thanks but how do I give this newly opened window its own WorkbenchWindowAdvisor, because I don't really want it to use the WorkbenchWindowAdvisor that the main application uses. I want this new window not to have the other fluff that its parent window (main application's window) has

Comment: Actually the problem with using this command is that it (seen from debugging) opens a new window with the active workbench windows perspective. And this is not what I want at all ... I want it to open a new window with its own WorkbenchWindowAdvisor and a completely different perspective with a single editor. The method: final IWorkbenchWindow window = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().openWorkbenchWindow("NewPerspectiveID", null); will work slightly better ... but still have a problem with it using a "custom" workbench window advisor so I can configure its shell style